# Find computer name by entering serial number

Tags: vbscript, wmi, serial-number

I have this script, which is able to search computer serial number by entering computer name. can you please help me to reverse it? So it will find computer name by entering serial number?

```
MyHostName = InputBox("Enter Machine Name")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
                    MyHostName & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSMBIOS = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_SystemEnclosure")
For Each objSMBIOS In colSMBIOS    
    pn = "Part Number: " & objSMBIOS.PartNumber
    sn = "Serial Number: " & objSMBIOS.SerialNumber
    sn1 = objSMBIOS.SerialNumber
    an = "Asset Tag: " & objSMBIOS.SMBIOSAssetTag
Next
tmp = InputBox(pn & VBCrLf & sn  & VBCrLf & an, "Computer Serial Number", sn1)
```

Comment: The code you have connects to the given computer and obtains the serial number from there. Since you cannot connect to a serial number you'd need a database mapping serial numbers to computer names for that kind of lookup to work.

Comment: With powershell, it may be possible... if the computer is in the network

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/376321-find-computer-name-from-serial-number

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar Yes, of course you can always take the trivial approach of connecting to every single computer and checking its serial number. That will work in VBScript as well, but depending on the size of the network and the online status of the computers it will take a very long time. And you need to have a list of all computers to begin with.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers If you're going to brute force it, why bother with a list? Just attempt to connect to every IP in network. (Note: this is NOT recommended!) ;)

Comment: @Tim, Ansgar didn't suggest that.  read the comment history again.

Comment: @Eddy, you could create a custom attribute in Active Directory and populate the Serial in that attribute then you can do the AD query to find them.  A logon script could populate the value for you so it is updated regularly.

Comment: @RLH Mithilesh suggested brute forcing it by connecting to every computer to check it SN. Ansgar pointed out that this would be inefficient because you'd still need a list of computers. I then made my tongue in cheek comment about making it even less elegant by simply scanning every IP. Please read and take the time to understand the comment history again. ;)